# Which role or permission allows user to share files in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint online site, what exactly is the role or permission that allows a user to share files?

Answer (score 0):

1.Users with any permission can share files with internal users.

2.Users with at least Edit permission can share files with external users.

Go to the site collection -> Site permissions settings -> Change how members can share -> Sharing permissions -> I suggest you choose "Site owners and members can share files, folder and the site.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you show has only owner/member can share, in that case how come anyone can share internally?

Comment: When a internal users click on share button then almost they can copy the link. They cannot share. So can you review check your point 1 please?